# SQL Order By with condition and brackets

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question regarding  below  SQL Queries,

if now is 13 below is the output of the SQL Query,

```
starts  ends  
 11     (13)  
 13     (14)  
 11     (15)
----------
(14)     19  
(15)     16  
(16)     21
----------
 9      (12)  
 8      (11)  
 10     (10)
```

As you can see that I have 3 condition,
The first one is

13 <= **end** AND 13 >= **start** ORDER BY **end** ASC

Then second one is

13 < **start** ORDER BY **start** ASC

Then third one is

13 > **end** ORDER BY **end** DESC

My solution is doing 3 queries and later in PHP I will combine these result into 1 result. Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Which DBMS you are using like SQLserver,Mysql,Oracle

Comment: I'm using Mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put multiple keys in an `order by`:

```
order by (case when 13 <= end and 13 >= start then 1
               when 13 > start then 2
               when 13 < start then 3
          end),
         (case when 13 <= end and 13 >= start then end end),
         (case when 13 < start then start end),
         (case when 13 < start then end end) desc
```

Comment: If this can return a lot of results, you may want to put the three separate queries into temp tables, union them, and then order by a sentinel value in each table.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.